# Objective-c class initializer executes multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, initializer

Unless I misunderstood it, this [**LINK**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) from Apple's documentation clearly states that the class initializer, "+ (void)initialize)", only executes once per class.

Here is the excerpt:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> initialize it is invoked only once per class. If you want to perform independent initialization for the class and for categories of the class, you should implement load methods.

However, I'm getting a weird behavior on my project and the initializer is being executed twice. So I have to check if _classContext is null. I only got one class that has this method. What are the possible reasons why this is happening?

I'm using XCode 4.5.2 and OS X 10.8.2. I got multiple iOS simulators, iPhone 5.1 and 6.0.

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    num++;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Times: %i", num]);
    if(_classContext == nil)
        _classContext = [[myClass alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: That's definitely weird. I've never come across it. You're not accessing it from multiple threads are you? The `+initialize` method will execute the first time the class is used for anything, so perhaps threading could trigger a double execution.

Comment: FWIW, you're referencing the OSx version of the doc, not the iOS version.  But I don't see any substantial differences.

Comment: Abhi Beckert - No, I'm not accessing it from multiple threads.

Comment: Please see my comments on rmaddy's answer. It seems to happen on auto generated classes from data models. I even tried using the default master detail application and it behaves the same. Thanks!

Comment: I hit the same. It was my xCode setup. I incorrectly added the Static Class method inside two Target Memberships (an app and a framework)

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you have a subclass of this class. The `initialize` method will be called for the class and each subclass.

The proper way to code the `initialize` method is:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    // Replace ThisClass with the actual class name
    if (self == [ThisClass class]) {
        // do initialization here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any subclass of this class but it is an auto generated class from my data model. I modified it and added the class initializer.

Here is the definition of my the class: @interface myEntityClass : NSManagedObject

Comment: rmaddy - I tried the class initializer on a non-auto generated class and it only executed once. Do you think auto generated classes from data model has something to do with this? Thanks!

Comment: rmaddy - I also tried it on an entirely new project (the default master detail application), auto generated the "Event" class from data model, added the class initializer, and it has the same behavior (initializer is being called twice). Thanks!

Comment: See what `self` is each of the two times. Perhaps a 2nd class is being generated. Regardless, the fix I suggest is the proper solution.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the solution you suggested and it works great. Thank you! I'm just trying to understand right now on why this is happening.

Comment: Did you look at `self` for each of the two executions?

Comment: Yes, `self` is the same class on each call.

Comment: Strange. I have an `initialize` method in a base class so the `initialize` method is called several times. But each time, `self` represents one of subclasses.

Comment: I used this code `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Times: %@", [self class]])` and it is displaying the same class name. But when I put it inside the `IF` on the above code you suggested, it was only executed once. This tells me that `self` is different on each call, sorry.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `if` statement and run the code. When the breakpoint is reader, enter `po self` and see what it says.

Comment: On the first call it says `(Class) $1 = 0x0001ad98 jatClsEntity` and the second call says `(Class) $2 = 0x06b84e60 jatClsEntity_ClsEntity_`. "jat" is the prefix I'm using for my class name.

Comment: There you go. One of these is a base class for the other. This is why `initialize` is called twice. Once for the base class and again for the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

+initialize can be called more than once and one should use caution when overriding +initialize.

Please read the blog post [+initialize Can Be Executed Multiple Times (+load not so much)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108095221/http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/) at bbum's weblog-o-mat.